# Check if D-Bus object exists

Tags: c, glib, dbus, gio

I am currently talking to ConsoleKit with GDBus. I used the ConsoleKit2 XML files and `gdbus-codegen` to generate the code. Everything is working fine. But how can I check if an object exists? For example I want to see if there is a `/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2` (just an example, I know I could enumerate all Sessions in the Seat object).

I tried using the `org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping` function, but that will return

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Seat1  org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping

Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.168" (uid=1000 pid=18279 comm="dbus-send --system --print-reply --reply-timeout=2") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer" member="Ping" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options, listed in order from most preferable to least preferable:

1. Enumerate all the sessions in the seat object using [`GetSessions()`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/ConsoleKit/doc/ConsoleKit.html#Seat.GetSessions).
2. Try and call the method you want on that session’s object path and see if it fails with an error from `org.freedesktop.DBus.Error`.
3. Call the [`Introspect()`](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-introspectable) method on `/org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit` and parse the `<node>` elements from the resulting XML blob to see the current object path hierarchy.

The first option is probably the easiest to implement, and is how you’re intended to use the ConsoleKit API. Note that seat and session numbering is not deterministic, so you shouldn’t just hard-code a session object path in your code, since that path might change on future boots.

Also note that, as the [ConsoleKit website](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/ConsoleKit/) says, ConsoleKit is deprecated in favour of [systemd-logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-logind.service.html), which you should consider using instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The idea number 2 came also across my mind, but i thought it would be ugly. Then it will be number 1. I know that its not deterministic, I just used the hardcoded path as an example. I also know that logind is the new way of doing this and the next step in my app will be logind support, but as some distributions still use consolekit (e.g. Gentoo Linux can still use Consolekit) I want to support both. Thank you again.